# How do I get the path to current .code-workspace file in the integrated shell?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When opening a .code-workspace file in VS Code, is there a way to get the file's path in the shell?

If a folder is opened in VS Code, we can retrieve its path using `${workspaceFolder}`. I would like to achieve something similar for the .code-workspace file as well.

I added the following configuration to settings.json:

```
"terminal.integrated.env.linux": {"VSCODE_WS": "${workspaceFolder}"}
```

After opening a .code-workspace file, `VSCODE_WS` is set to the path of one of the folders opened in the workspace. However, I want to obtain the path to the .code-workspace file itself. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible (although I'd be happy to be wrong!).

See [Support a variable that resolves to the location of the code-workspace file #50372](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/50372), which got enough community support to get added to the VS Code development backlog, but was eventually [closed with the message](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/50372#issuecomment-1339388475):

> We closed this issue because we [don't plan to address it](https://aka.ms/vscode-out-of-scope) in the foreseeable future. If you disagree and feel that this issue is crucial: we are happy to listen and to reconsider. [...]

If you think it's a crucial feature to have, I encourage you to describe your use-case and why you think it's a crucial feature in that thread and give the thread a thumbs up reaction.

I don't know of a workaround. Even if you tried scanning the whole filesystem for files and then parsed the JSON to see which ones point to the current `${workspaceFolder}`, I don't see what you would do if multiple .code-workspace files get found meeting that condition.

For your reference / learning purposes, I found the above issue ticket by googling "`github vscode issues variable for code-workspace file`".